# Command line input, extreme, and map patterns python

Tags: python

I'm doing work for my intro level CS class and I'm not really sure how to solve this task. Here it is:

> Create a program that takes command line input to obtain the data and
>   process the data using a list. Here is how the program should behave:
>
> ```
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/cs150/loops$ python3 command.py 11 5 3 51
> the smallest number is 3
> ```
>
> To convert the arguments to integers, use the map pattern, as in:
>
> ```
> strings = ArrayToList(sys.argv[1:])
> numbers = ListMap(int,strings)
> ```
>
> The ListMap function is already defined for you in [List.py](http://troll.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/List.py), which you
>   can download with:
>
> ```
> wget troll.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/List.py
> ```
>
> You will need to import the List and sys modules in your program:
>
> ```
> import sys
> from List import *
> ```
>
> Finally, use the extreme pattern for lists to find and print the
>   smallest integer once ListMap has converted the argument strings into
>   ints.

Here is what I have:

```
import sys
from List import *

def main():
   strings = ArrayToList(sys.argv[1:])
   numbers = ListMap(int,strings)
   smallest = numbers[0]
   for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
      if (numbers[i] < smallest):
        smallest = numbers[i]
   print("The smallest number is: ", smallest)
main()
```

Here's the error message I receive from this code:

```
File "command.py", line 12, in <module>
  main()
File "command.py", line 9, in main
  if (numbers[i] < smallest):
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
```

Sorry this is such a long post, I just really need some help as I am new to coding and I wanted to be thorough. Not sure where I'm going wrong or what I need to add/change, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `ListMap` contain both `int` and `list` elements? Try printing out each `numbers[i]` in your loop, before the `if` statement. Also print `type(numbers[i])` so you know their type. Updating your question with what gets printed would help.

Comment: No need to `range(0, len(numbers))` in Python. Just `for number in numbers`. Geez, you even unnecessarily specified a step of 1! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list's internal representation is in fact a *list of lists*, looking like this: `['4', ['2', ['5', ['1', ['0', None]]]]]`.  You should use the `head` and `tail` functions from the `List.py` module to get the first element of the list:

```
while numbers:
    num, numbers = head(numbers), tail(numbers)
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num
```

Note that given this implementation of a list, a recursive implementation might be more natural:

```
def get_smallest(lst):
    h, t = head(lst), tail(lst)
    return min(h, get_smallest(t)) if t else h
smallest = get_smallest(numbers)
```

Comment: This is correct. Essentially the instructor is not a Python programmer, and is doing the equivalent of functional programming in a very confusing module with a lot of overwritten built-in stuff, plus some stuff that is just blatantly wrong (like `!= None`). Since he's trying to replicate curried functions, best to just use his stuff on it, because it won't play nice with normal Python stuff unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame you have to use your instructor's strangely spelled functions (functions are supposed to be lowercase according to the ubiquitous [PEP8 Style Guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in Python).

You could complete this whole assignment in 3 lines of Python 3:

```
# command.py
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(min(map(int, sys.argv[1:])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search for the smallest value manually, you can just do this:

```
smallest = sorted(numbers)[0]
```

I am not sure what the `numbers` type is, but if its a `List` this will work. Otherwise, you can specify a sorting key like this:

```
smallest = sorted(numbers, key=some_key)[0]
```

The `key` is a method of comparation of elements.

Comment: You don't even need to do that. You can just use `min`.